# CSS and Bootstrap responsive - full sized tabs and navigation in theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have this page http://www.maxsecure.cz/catalog/show/?hotelId=4

You can see here in middle "Room Details" section with table an Overview section with tabs.
I need to have this Overview section with tabs full sized of content div.
How I can do it please?

And also in another tab have full sized table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), you can arrange width of columns with the so called `col-*-*` classes.

Your Overview section has a class called `col-sm-5`. The total columns in a row are 12 (i.e full width) So if you change `col-sm-5` to `col-sm-12`, then your Overview section spans the full width.